# Large index producing error in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scipy

I have a folder train in which I have 13000 images of animals. I want to use a deep neural network to train them. But the images are of different sizes, so I run the following code to get a numpy array X .

```
for i in range(m):
  my_image = "Img-"+str(i+1)+".jpg"
  fname = "train/train/"+my_image
  image = plt.imread(fname)
  X[i] = scipy.misc.imresize(image, size=(num_px,num_px)).reshape((1, num_px*num_px*3))
```

This works fine for values of m upto 1000. But when m=13000 , the size of my training set, it gives the following error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-c214b5b43e33> in <module>()
      3     fname = "train/train/"+my_image
      4     image = plt.imread(fname)
----> 5     X[i] = scipy.misc.imresize(image, size=(num_px,num_px)).reshape((1, num_px*num_px*3))
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 40000 into shape (1,120000)
```

Here the imresize() is to resize the image into desired size. My num_px value is 256. 
Any help would be highly appreciable

Comment: Doesn't this mean that images 1..1000 are ok, but somewhere between 1001..13000 there's at least one image which cannot be resized? I suggest enclosing the `imresize` line in a `try..except` block, and printing out `i` in the `except` clause. Then poke at that JPEG file in an interactive shell to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

One of your images is a grayscale image, not an RGB image. 
Note that [`help(plt.imread)`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imread.html) says (my emphasis):

> Return value is a `numpy.array`.  **For grayscale images, the
>   return array is MxN**.  For RGB images, the return value is MxNx3.

`scipy.misc.imresize(image, size=(num_px,num_px))`
is returning an array of shape `(num_px,num_px)`, not `(num_px,num_px,3)`.
Hence, the array cannot be reshape to `(1, num_px*num_px*3)`.

(Notice that 40000 is exactly one third of 120000.)

---

To convert all images to RGB you could use:

```
from PIL import Image
for i in range(m):
    my_image = "Img-"+str(i+1)+".jpg"
    fname = "train/train/"+my_image
    img = np.asarray(Image.open(fname).convert('RGB'))
    X[i] = scipy.misc.imresize(image, size=(num_px,num_px)).reshape((1, num_px*num_px*3))
```

---

To future-proof your code, also note that [`help(scipy.misc.imresize)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imresize.html) says (my emphasis):

> `imresize` is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and will be removed in 1.2.0.
>   **Use `skimage.transform.resize` instead**.